# Interactivity Triggers and Generic properties?

Tags: c#, generics, xaml, mvvm

I've created a `TriggerBase` class, name `CollectionContainsValueTrigger`. As its name suggests, the trigger invokes the action whenever it contains a certain value.

However, I would like to create the trigger so it acts in such a way that it accepts all kinds of `ObservableCollection` of `T`, not just an explicit typed of `ObservableCollection`. I tried `ObservableCollection` of object but the binding doesn't work because the Type is different from my `ViewModel`'s explicitly typed `ObservableCollection`.

How can I do this?

xaml example:

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <mi:CollectionContainsValueTrigger Collection="{Binding SomeStronglyTypedViewModelCollection}" Value="Some Value">
      <SomeAction />
    </mi:CollectionContainsValueTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: -What does it do  with instances of ObservableCollection<T> ?
-Do you pass an instance as parameter or you want to hold on to it (e.g.in a property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i realized that xaml does not support Generics currently, only in the future version. if it does, it would have solved my problem....

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to suggest without seeing some examples of what you are trying to acheive.

If i understand correctly your non-generic class needs polymorphic access to some generic-based classes (like ObservableCollection) of different types

To accomodate this I would use a polymorphic adapter:

```
class ObservableCollectionAdapterBase 
{
  virtual void Method1(){}
  virtual void Method2(){}
}

class ObservableCollectionAdapter<T, TCollectionType> : ObservableCollectionAdapterBase 
where TCollectionType : IObservableCollection<T> 
{
   public ObservableCollectionAdapter(TCollectionType collection)
   {
      _collection = collection;
   }

   override void Method1(){ _collection.DoSomething(); }
   override void Method2(){ _collection.DoSomething(); }
}
```